# In a git diff, can I show only deletions that aren't followed by an addition?

Tags: git, diff

I'd like to be able to show deletions in git diff that aren't followed by an addition.
That is, only show `-` lines that aren't followed by `+` lines. Is that possible?

Comment: Not using Git directly. You can have Git, or any other tool, *generate* the diff, then examine and edit it yourself, in your own code. Or, you can use a differencing engine to come up with the edit sequence, and do your own work with that.

Answer (score 1):

```
git diff | awk '/^@/{ if(s) print p; s = 1; p="" } 
    s == 1 && /^\+/ { s = 0 } 1 {p = sprintf("%s\n%s", p, $0)} 
    END { if (s) print p }' s=2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
git diff --numstat | awk '/^0/ {print $3}'
```

From the `git-diff` manpage:

> The --numstat option gives the diffstat(1) information but is designed
> for easier machine consumption. An entry in --numstat output looks
> like this:
>
> ```
> 1       2       README
> 3       1       arch/{i386 => x86}/Makefile
> ```
>
> That is, from left to right:
>
> 1. **the number of added lines;**
> 2. a tab;
> 3. the number of deleted lines;
> 4. a tab;
> 5. pathname (possibly with rename/copy information);
> 6. a newline.

Answer (score 0):

With a little black magic, yes.

## Step 1

We need to understand that

`git diff`

lists files, change sets, removals, additions and some lines around them

## Step 2

We need to remove all superfluous lines, so that we get only the files and the changes inside them, like this:

```
git diff | grep '^\(\+\+\+\|---\|-\|\+\)'
```

## Step 3

Write a program that runs the command seen at Step 2 and displays the result. I know this is not yet the solution, but you will absolutely need this step to be performed first, so we know that the input and the output are working.

## Step 4

Now, let's apply filtering. A very simple filter would be performed by this algorithm

```
deletedLines <- empty
for each line
    if (line starts with --- or +++) then add line to output
    else if (line starts with -) deletedLines.add(line)
    else
        if (line starts with + but not with +++) then clear deletedLines
        else add deletedLines to output
end for
```

Comment: `git diff | grep '^\(+++\|---\|-\|+\)'` didn't work for me.

Comment: @Geremia can you elaborate on how it did not work for you?

Comment: It produced no output.

Comment: @Geremia can you formulate a question where you provide the details to reproduce this and share the link to it here? I would like to investigate the matter.

Comment: ["git diff | grep '^\(+++\|---\|-\|+\)'" produces no output.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76808588/1429450) It could be because the output of my diff is colorized.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution, in a single line, and using just regular expressions. Here, I use `rg`, but any grep tool that supports multiline matching and inverse matching (`-U` and `-v`, respectively) will work.

```
git diff | rg '^(\+ |- ).*' | rg -vU '^-(.*)\n\+(.*)\n'
```