# "git diff | grep '^\(+++\|---\|-\|+\)'" produces no output

Tags: git, grep, diff

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68635779/1429450), when I run this on a git repo with changes, no output is produced

```
git diff | grep '^\(+++\|---\|-\|+\)'
```

But when I run just `git diff`, this output is produced:

```
diff --git a/CMakeLists.txt b/CMakeLists.txt
index 7971704..031964f 100644
--- a/CMakeLists.txt
+++ b/CMakeLists.txt
@@ -423,7 +423,7 @@ if (WITH_CUDA)
       list(APPEND CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS "-Xcompiler=/MT$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:d>")
     endif()
   else()
-    list(APPEND CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS "-std=c++17")
+    list(APPEND CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS "-std=c++20")
   endif()
   if(OpenMP_CXX_FOUND)
     list(APPEND CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS "-Xcompiler=${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS}")
```

It could be because the output of my diff is colorized.

Comment: If you want only changed lines without the context, you could use `git diff -U0`

Comment: As [you've said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68634522/in-a-git-diff-can-i-show-only-deletions-that-arent-followed-by-an-addition/68635779#comment135408786_68635779) it could be because of color output. Try `git diff --color=never | grep '^\(+++\|---\|-\|+\)'`

Comment: + is a special character meaning 1 or more of the previous char. So it needs escaping.

Comment: Tested this by pasting the output of your diff into a file and then running `cat myfile.txt | grep '^\(\+\+\+\|---\|-\|\+\)'` and the output was exactly as expected. Probably your `---` and `+++` has some characters injected. Try exporting your diff into a file via `> youroutput.txt` so your output will be exported and let us know what you see in the file.

Comment: @patthoyts thanks for pointing that out, edited my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68634522/in-a-git-diff-can-i-show-only-deletions-that-arent-followed-by-an-addition/68635779?noredirect=1#comment135408786_68635779 accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of color output. This works:

```
git diff --color=never | grep '^\(+++\|---\|-\|+\)'
```